# Return A Single Variable From Array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, location

i am using following script:

http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-zip-code-range-and-distance-calculation.html

To get the details for a ZIP code, I am using this:

```
$selected = $z->get_zip_details($zip);
$result = implode(",", $selected);
echo $result;
```

This returns all details of "$zip" :

32.9116,-96.7323,Dallas,Dallas,TX,Texas,214,Central

Could any1 help me to make the script return ONLY the city variable? The FAQ of the script, says the following:

```
get_zip_details($zip)

Returns the details about the zip code: $zip. Details are in the form of a keyed array. The keys are: latitude, longitude, city, county, state_prefix, state_name, area_code, and time_zone. All are pretty self-explanitory. Returns false on error.
```

Unfortunately I cant figure out how to get a single value (city). Would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions is returning an array, so we have to store it in a variable.

```
    $selected = $z->get_zip_details($zip);
```

Next, we can select the key which points to the city. The key is also called city.

```
  echo $selected['city'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried to do echo $get_zip_details['city']; and much more! It now works fine and I will remeber it for the future :)

Answer (score 1):

**Change this line**

```
$result = implode(",", $selected);
```

**To**

```
$result = $selected['city'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, `implode()` `explode()` etc. are array functions.  So, if you're using them on something then you can `print_r()` it to see its structure.

If you had done `print_r($selected);` or `var_dump($selected);`, you would have gotten something like this as output:

```
Array ( [x] => 32.9116 [y] =>-96.7323 [city] => Dallas [state] => Texas [etc] => etc )
```

So you can see the keys of the array to know how to access the individual values.